# Problem about inequality with symetric matrices and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices of order $n$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.
$\newcommand{\lg}{\langle}$ $\newcommand{\rg}{\rangle}$

a) If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric then 
$$ \lg(A^{2} + B^{2})x, x \rg  \geq  \lg(AB+BA)x,x\rg $$ 
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $\lg,\rg$ means the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**hint**: Consider $\lg(A-B)^{2}x,x\rg.$

b) If $A$ and $B$ are not symmetric then find a counterexample.

c) If $C$ is other matrix of order $n$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lg Cx,x\rg  =  \lg Bx,x\rg$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, what can you say about $B-C$?,don't suppose $B$ is symmetric.

I tried use the hint but I don't see why help, I got $$\lg (A-B)^{2}x,x\rg = \lg (A^{2}-AB-BA+B^{2})x,x\rg  = \lg (A^{2}+B^{2})x,x\rg - \lg (AB+BA)x,x\rg$$

Comment: Hint: $\langle (A-B)^2x,x\rangle =\langle (A-B)x,(A-B)x\rangle $ if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric

Comment: To the last line, you only have to add that $(A-B)^2$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your problem focuses on part a). The key is that since $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric, then so is $A-B$ and thus
$$0\le\langle(A-B)x,(A-B)x\rangle=\langle(A-B)^2x,x\rangle,
$$
and then the conclusion follows your calculation.